# An if function that returns specified text if the selection contains a word

Tags: excel

I need to create a function (or macro, which ever is easier) in excel that returns "Text1" if a selection CONTAINS "Specified Text1" or if it contains "Specified Text2" then return "Text2" and if it contains "Specified Text3" then return a value of "Text3".

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: Is "Text1" a substring of "Specified Text1" like "Turtle" is a substring of "Turtle Soup" or are the two uniqe strings like "Turtle" and "Dumb Dog"?

Comment: if i got you right, you have "abc, "def" and "ghi" to search for in "hstdefhrk" while having "123", "456" and "789" as output => you want to get "456"... is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Till further clarification i asume your question to like in my comment asked:

> if i got you right, you have "abc, "def" and "ghi" to search for in "hstdefhrk" while having "123", "456" and "789" as output => you want to get "456"... is that correct?

To get this by formula:

```
'case sensitive
=INDEX({"";"OutputText1";"OutputText2";"OutputText3"},MAX(ROW($1:$4)*ISNUMBER(FIND({"";"SearchText1";"SearchText2";"SearchText3"},A1))))

'not case sensitive
=INDEX({"";"OutputText1";"OutputText2";"OutputText3"},MAX(ROW($1:$4)*ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"";"SearchText1";"SearchText2";"SearchText3"},A1))))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

For doing it as an UDF try this: (not case sensitive)

```
Public Function multiSearch(sourceStr As String, srcMatrix As Variant, dstMatrix As Variant, Optional caseSen As Boolean) As String
  Dim runner As Variant, i As Long
  For Each runner In srcMatrix
    If InStr(1, sourceStr, runner, caseSen + 1) Then Exit For
    i = i + 1
  Next
  For Each runner In dstMatrix
    If i = 0 Then
      multiSearch = runner
      Exit For
    Else
      i = i - 1
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

And use it like `LOOKUP`

```
=multiSearch([striong to search in],[array of strings to search for],[array of strings to output],[1/true for case sensitive])

=multiSearch(A1,{"SearchText1";"SearchText2";"SearchText3"},{"OutputText1";"OutputText2";"OutputText3"}) 'not case sensitive
=multiSearch(A1,D1:D6,E1:E6,1) 'case sensitive
```

Comment: I changed the delimeter for windows to `.` so in excel the seperator changes from `;` to `,`... but there may be a difference for arrays not fetching that up correctly (i get the formulas always with `?selection.formula` in vba cus `LEFT` is `LINKS` for me and all that stuff... while vba changes it to english, it doesn't change the delimeter)

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1, SEARCH("specified ", A1)+10, LEN(A1)), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the actual strings are not "Specified Text" and some number.  That they are in fact separate unique strings.

You could use nested if statements:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Specified Text1",A1))),"Text1",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Specified Text2",A1))),"Text2",IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Specified Text3",A1))),"Text3","")))
```

Comment: If A1 conatins Specified Text14 than your formula will return Text1 and not Text14.

Comment: @ManishChristian, yes, but see my assumption.  I am assuming that the text provided by the OP are place holders and not the actual text that only have a number as different.

Comment: You are right based on your assumption.

Comment: @DirkReichel, I know that and that's the reason I gave +1 to the answer from Jeeped.

Comment: just as a sugestion, you could flip your formula to: `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("SpecIFied Text1",A1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("SpecIFied Text2",A1)),IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("SpecIFied Text3",A1)),"","Text3"),"Text2"),"Text1")` or directly skip it to: `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Specified Text1",A1),"Text1"),IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Specified Text2",A1),"Text2"),IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Specified Text3",A1),"Text3"),"")))`

Comment: @DirkReichel yes, if you go back through my edits you will see I was just adding to a formula to get what I wanted.  If I had started from scratch I probably would have done the second one.  I tend to keep adding to what I have even if I am going down the wrong path :).

Comment: @DirkReichel I had posted the first If statement and was working on an index/match when it was pointed out by pnuts that I missed something, so I fixed it and went back to the index/match just to have you beat me to it.

Comment: right now, it is still not clear what the OP need, so you simply CAN'T go the wrong path at all :D was just a sugestion to flip `IF(NOT(ISERROR(,)),,nested)` to `IF(ISERROR(,),nested,)` to skip out the `NOT` or to `IFERROR(IF(,),nested)` by flip `IF/ISERROR` to `IFERROR/IF`...

Comment: oh.. a third way to improve your formula: just switch `NOT(ISERROR` to `ISNUMBER` ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel <Sarcasm> Now your just showing off</Sarcasm>.  I like your suggestions and will use them in the future, but your formulas are better and if we are correct about the input/output, yours should be chosen as correct.  I would change my answer to one of your suggestions, but I have a hard time putting more work into something to which the OP can not find the time to answer a few questions.

Comment: I want to vote for an "can't ask any new questions vote"-function in here... or better "can't see any answers at own questions vote"-function :D lots of "On Hold"-questions would be solved :D