# How to do multiple lookup and results in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm managing status of IPs and here is what I need:

Look for a A1 in Sheet2!A:A, if found return text1, if not look in Sheet2!B:B, if found return text2, if not return text3.

Comment: This feels like [deja vu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295649/an-if-function-that-returns-specified-text-if-the-selection-contains-a-word) even if different.

Comment: Where does text1 come from?

Comment: @findwindow its not i tried that "deja vu" but it didn't work like i want it but thanks to Demetri now all is good.

Comment: @dacrovinunghi if i knew how to use it i wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: At least you can try a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,SHEET2!A:A,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,SHEET2!B:B,0)),text3,tex2),text1)
```

Comment: This works as long as the return text is something hard coded and not related to the value in A1 on the various sheets.  If there is a relation, then using a vlookup inside iferror would work better, but the OP has not answered the question, and any guess is as good as another.